# How to automatically generate subtitles for a video and translate them in NextJS

Tags: next.js, openai-whisper, whisper

I want to do the following:

1. User logging in to my website
2. He click "upload video" and choose the video from the disc
3. Video is uploaded to cloud
4. Once it's uploaded, the speech from video (no matter what langueage it is) should be converted to text and then translated to english.
5. File with captions should be saved so that user can pick them from the "Subtitles" menu in video player.

The tricky point is 4) because I don't know which software could I use to generate subtitles from video and translate them to english (and possibly other languages). I found `Whisper AI` from `OpenAI` and I'm wondering whether I should use this one or something else. Also, it's a Python library and I'm wondering how can I actually call this when upload finished. I'm using NextJS.   ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package written in nodejs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai

```js
import fs from "fs";
import OpenAI from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI();

async function main() {
  const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
    file: fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"), // formats: flac, mp3, mp4, mpeg, mpga, m4a, ogg, wav, or webm.
    model: "whisper-1",
  });

  console.log(transcription.text);
}
main();
```